# Query parameter in a literal to the right of a LIKE operator

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I am trying to run a query using ODP.NET. The query has a parameter in the literal to the right of a `LIKE` operator. Here is my code:

```
string query = @"select col1,col2,col3 from table where name like '%:cus_name%'";
OracleParameter p1 = new OracleParameter();
p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Char;
p1.Value = name;
p1.ParameterName = "cus_name";

OracleCommand sql = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
sql.Parameters.Add(p1);
OracleDataReader ora = null;
```

I receive an "Invalid parameter" error. Kindly advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your

```
like '%:cus_name%'
```

to

```
like  '%' || :cus_name || '%'
```

The problem is here quotes. In quotes, your *[rdms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)* will recognize it as a *[string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)* and **never** sees it as a parameter.